# HTML5: tab management

Tags: html

Does HTML5 allow JavaScript to open, close, or switch to a tab in the browser?  Can I call a JavaScript function to perform these in any HTML5 browser?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, javascript or HTML5 has nothing to do with switching tabs of browser. You can open/close/focus popup windows though.

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard API for that.

You can only do it if you create a browser extension in [Chrome](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/packages/addon-kit/docs/tabs.html) or [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH17-SW1)

You will be able to control the tabs from Javascript but that will work only for those users that explicitly installed the extension in each browser.